# Cant navigate into a specific column sqlite

Tags: sqlite

The first link is the problems.

I am very inexperienced in SQLite and needed some help.

Thanks in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg0hS.jpg

These are all the tables displayed open

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGPGL.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUUdk.jpg

The schema

https://imgur.com/a/bv5KTHN

This is as far as I could get which is close but I couldn't figure out how to sort it also by marina 1.

```
SELECT BOAT_NAME, OWNER.OWNER_NUM, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME from OWNER inner join MARINA_SLIP on OWNER.OWNER_NUM = MARINA_SLIP.OWNER_NUM;
```

If you know anything else bout the other questions feel free to help me with those too, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want

```
SELECT BOAT_NAME, OWNER.OWNER_NUM, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME 
FROM OWNER INNER JOIN MARINA_SLIP ON OWNER.OWNER_NUM = MARINA_SLIP.OWNER_NUM 
WHERE MARINA_NUM = 1 
ORDER BY BOAT_NAME;
```

The second question involves multiple joins.

The third question asks you to use the [count(*)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count) function, noting that this is an aggregate function and will result in the number of rows for the GROUP as per the [GROUP BY clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) (if no GROUP BY clause then there is just the one GROUP i.e. all resultant rows).

The fourth question progresses a little further asking you to extend the GROUP BY clause with the HAVING clause (see link above for GROUP BY).